# How to see post back data on any view page in laravel which uses blade template system?

Tags: php, post, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

How can I print post back data on any view page in Laravel framework which uses blade template system.

$_POST['state'] is not giving any results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Laravel encapsulates the whole request data in the `Input` Facade, so you just have to:

```
State: {{ Input::get('state') }}
```

or, if you're trying to read data from a redirected request:

```
State: {{ Input::old('state') }}
```

You can use conditionals this way in Blade:

```
@if(Input::get('state'))
   <button ...>
@endif
```

Comment: can I use like this `<?php if(?>{{Input::get('state')}}<?php ){?> `

Comment: You could use it this way: <?php if(Input::get('state')){?>. But I just edited with a better one, using pure blade.